# https redirected to https for one page of site in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https

I have a link to a secure quote form on my site, which I changed to a different secure URL. I am showing 404's for the old URL. I have tried numerous ways to redirect using .htaccess to no avail. Can someone help?

Here's the code I am using--but it does not work. All other pages of the site are http (not secure). Only the quote form is secure.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^rvinsurancepro\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.rvinsurancepro\.com$
RewriteRule ^quotes\/rv\-insurance\/$ "https\:\/\/iig\.itismysite\.com\/quotes\/rv\-insurance\/" [R=301,L]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but you may have missed a slash at the beginning of your RewriteRule.

```
RewriteRule ^/quotes\/rv\-insurance\/$ "https://yourdomain.com/xxx" [R=301,L]
```

should do the job.

Just as an addition, you could combine your HTTP_HOST entries to:

```
^(www\.)?rvinsurancepro\.com$
```

I am also not sure, that second argument of the RewriteRule directive takes an regular
expression so you may not need to escape the dots and slashes. It works with and without
escaping.